# Custom cross-hatched background shape or view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, draw, shapes

I am trying to create a shaded cross-hatched. But so far I can do it by adding a Image.

How can I create a custom view in which lines will be drawn and not filled with a Image?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("lineFilledBG").resizable().clipShape(Circle())
            Circle().stroke()
            Circle().foregroundColor(.yellow).opacity(0.3)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This is how it looks now. Want lines to draw on top of another view or shape, without adding opacity and image pattern filling.

[image: Cross-hatched shape]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank to [Cenk Bilgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190619/cenk-bilgen) for stripe pattern. Tweaked a bit so that you can rotate the hatch for any shape.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

extension CGImage {

    static func generateStripePattern(
        colors: (UIColor, UIColor) = (.clear, .black),
        width: CGFloat = 6,
        ratio: CGFloat = 1) -> CGImage? {

    let context = CIContext()
    let stripes = CIFilter.stripesGenerator()
    stripes.color0 = CIColor(color: colors.0)
    stripes.color1 = CIColor(color: colors.1)
    stripes.width = Float(width)
    stripes.center = CGPoint(x: 1-width*ratio, y: 0)
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: 1)

    guard
        let stripesImage = stripes.outputImage,
        let image = context.createCGImage(stripesImage, from: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    else { return nil }
    return image
  }
}

extension Shape {

    func stripes(angle: Double = 45) -> AnyView {
        guard
            let stripePattern = CGImage.generateStripePattern()
        else { return AnyView(self)}

        return AnyView(Rectangle().fill(ImagePaint(
            image: Image(decorative: stripePattern, scale: 1.0)))
        .scaleEffect(2)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle))
        .clipShape(self))
    }
}
```

And usage

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .stripes(angle: 30)
            Circle().stripes()
            Capsule().stripes(angle: 90)
        }
    }
}
```

[Output image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1vG3.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but CoreImage can generate a striped pattern.

```
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins
import SwiftUI

extension CGImage {
  // width is for total, ratio is second stripe relative to full width
  static func stripes(colors: (UIColor, UIColor), width: CGFloat, ratio: CGFloat) -> CGImage {
    let filter = CIFilter.stripesGenerator()
    filter.color0 = CIColor(color: colors.0)
    filter.color1 = CIColor(color: colors.1)
    filter.width = Float(width-width*ratio) 
    filter.center = CGPoint(x: width, y: 0)
    let size = CGSize(width: width+width*ratio, height: 1)
    let bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    // keep a reference to a CIContext if calling this often
    return CIContext().createCGImage(filter.outputImage!.clamped(to: bounds), from: bounds)!
  }
}
```

then use ImagePaint

```
 Circle().fill(
   ImagePaint(image: Image(decorative: CGImage.stripes(colors: (.blue, .yellow), width: 80, ratio: 0.25), scale: 1))
   )
   .rotationEffect(.degrees(-30))
```

Or `CILineScreen` filter may be more what you want.

Comment: It works with a circle, but when you need to rotate the hatching into other shapes it turns out like [this](https://yadi.sk/i/XUJ6AOsxiIdoeA)

Comment: Yes, it only generates vertical stripes. So if you want to rotate the end result to an arbitrary angle, it really only works for a circle.  To make it work for any shape you could apply a rotation transform at the image creation stage.

Comment: thank you. added rotation based on your answer, I hope I understood you correctly)) Please see my answer

Comment: One thing that bit me (that looks like it's fixed in @flyer2001's solution) is that rotating the Image passed into ImagePaint doesn't work like you'd think. It looks like that spits out an `SwiftUI.ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.Image, SwiftUI._RotationEffect>` view under the hood, rather than a new SwiftUI.Image.

Comment: If you need the final result to be an Image and not a View, adjust the function to apply the rotation or whatever transform to the CIImage, then set the CGImage bounds to the size of the final image you want. Then initialize the SwiftUI Image from that CGImage.

Answer (score 2):

I`m not sure what do you want but another possible solution is using different backgrounds in a ZStack linear gradient and shadows to make convex or concave effect., for this it helps that your background with a little color, not white white. some samples:

[image]

The code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.opacity(0.1)
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                myCircle()
                myCircle1()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct myCircle: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle().foregroundColor(Color.clear)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(
                ZStack {
                    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1) ), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.clear, lineWidth: 10)
                        .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), radius: 3, x: -5, y: -5)
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.clear, lineWidth: 10)
                        .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1)), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                }
            )
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .shadow(color: Color( #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) ), radius: 20, x: -20, y: -20)
            .shadow(color: Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1) ), radius: 20, x: 20, y: 20)
    }
}

struct myCircle1: View {
   
    var body: some View {
       Circle().foregroundColor(Color.clear)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .background(
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color( #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) ), Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1))]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.clear, lineWidth: 10)
                    .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)), radius: 3, x: -5, y: -5)
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.clear, lineWidth: 10)
                    .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1)), radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
            }
        )
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .shadow(color: Color( #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) ), radius: 20, x: -20, y: -20)
        .shadow(color: Color( #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1) ), radius: 20, x: 20, y: 20)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to  [Cenk Bilgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190619/cenk-bilgen) and [flyer2001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3757640/flyer2001), I edited the code and come up with this code so it can be used with a view.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

extension CGImage {

    static func generateStripePattern(
        colors: (UIColor, UIColor) = (.clear, .black),
        width: CGFloat = 6,
        ratio: CGFloat = 1) -> CGImage? {

    let context = CIContext()
    let stripes = CIFilter.stripesGenerator()
    stripes.color0 = CIColor(color: colors.0)
    stripes.color1 = CIColor(color: colors.1)
    stripes.width = Float(width)
    stripes.center = CGPoint(x: 1 - (width * ratio), y: 0)
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: 1)

    guard
        let stripesImage = stripes.outputImage,
        let image = context.createCGImage(stripesImage, from: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    else { return nil }
    return image
  }
}

struct ViewStripes : ViewModifier {
    
    var stripeColor : Color
    var width : CGFloat
    var ratio : CGFloat
    var angle : Double
    var frameW : CGFloat
    var frameH : CGFloat
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        if let stripePattern = CGImage.generateStripePattern(colors: (.clear,UIColor(stripeColor)), width: width, ratio: ratio) {
  
            content
                .overlay(Rectangle().fill(ImagePaint(image: Image(decorative: stripePattern, scale: 1.0)))
                            .frame(width: hypotenuse((frameW / 2), frameH / 2) * 2, height: hypotenuse(frameW / 2, frameH / 2) * 2)
                            //.scaleEffect(1)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle))
                            .mask(content))
        }
    }
}

extension View {

    func drawStripes(stripeColor: Color, width: CGFloat, ratio: CGFloat, angle : Double, frameW : CGFloat, frameH : CGFloat) -> some View {
        modifier(ViewStripes(stripeColor: stripeColor, width: width, ratio: ratio, angle: angle, frameW: frameW, frameH: frameH))
        
    }
}

func hypotenuse(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Double {
    return (a * a + b * b).squareRoot()
}
```

And for usage:

```
Rectangle()
         .foregroundColor(Color.Red)
         .frame(width:20, height: 20)

         //This is the code itself
         .drawStripes(stripeColor: Color.white, width: 3, ratio: 0.9, angle: 45, frameW: 20, frameH: 20)
```

Hope it may be helpful for someone.